# Align types in type annotation Python

Tags: python, python-typing

I want the arguments of a function to be a `list` and a `Callable` that can be called upon the type of `list` elements, i.e.:

```py
import typing as tp

def foo(list_: list[T], func_: tp.Callable[[T], tp.Any]):
    func_(list_[0])
```

I don't care what the type `T` is, I only care if `func_` can be called upon `T`.
Is there a way to annotate the function and not require a specific type of list elements?

Comment: If you add `T = tp.TypeVar("T")`, what you've posted [_works_](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=db7ba1936bb3f501ee338fcd6a49b6dd). That _is_ how you describe the relationship between the elements in the list and the parameter of the function, it _doesn't_ require a specific type of the list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `T` a `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")

def foo(arr: list[T], func: Callable[[T], U]) -> None:
    func(arr[0])
```

Within a given call to `foo`, the `arr` and `func` arguments must have the same `T`:

```
foo(["asdf", "foo"], lambda x: x.replace("a", "b"))  # ok
foo([1, 2, 3], lambda x: x + 1)                      # ok
foo([1, 2, 3], lambda x: x.replace("foo", "bar"))    # error
```

I suggest using another `TypeVar` as a placeholder for the return value because `Any` can easily lead to uncaught errors in the future, whereas a `TypeVar` with no bound will error if you make bad assumptions about what it supports:

```
def foo(arr: list[T], func: Callable[[T], Any]) -> None:
    x = func(arr[0]) + 2  # ok  (danger!)
```

```
def foo(arr: list[T], func: Callable[[T], U]) -> None:
    x = func(arr[0]) + 2  # error  (good!)
```

If you intend for `func` to always be a function that returns `None`, just specify `None` instead of either `U` or `Any`.